# ImportError: No module named django.core.mail

Tags: django, email, edx

I tried to enable the email functionality of edx, and I followed these steps.

1. To get the emails working, all you have to do is the following,
2. Go to cms\envs\common.py
3. Go to the email portion. Should start with a comment, # Email.
4. Change EMAIL_BACKEND to 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
5. Change the DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL to the email you want to use. Similarly,
6. for DEFAULT_FEEDBACK_EMAIL and SERVER_EMAIL
7. Set EMAIL_HOST to the host of your choice. (e.g - 'smtp.google.com' for Gmail.)
8. Set EMAIL_HOST_USER to your email id and EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD to your password.
9. Set EMAIL_PORT to the port your server uses (587 for Gmail.)
10. Set EMAIL_USE_TLS to True or False according to your server. (True for Gmail.)

However, when I tried to make a test like this:

```
>>> from django.core.mail import EmailMessage
>>> email = EmailMessage('Hello', 'World', to=['youremail@somewhere.com'])
>>> email.send()
```

the error occured:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module
ImportError: No module named django.core.mail
```

I'm a beginner and I've no idea about how to solve this. I've tried to search for solution on the internet and on the websites of Django and edx, but I still don't even have a clue. Could anyone help me with this please? Much appreciate.

Comment: Did you install django?

Comment: How did you start the Python interpreter? You should use `manage.py shell`.

Answer (score 0):

Probably your `PYTHONPATH` variable is not set correctly. Start django like this:

```
./manage.py shell
```

and try this command:

```
import django
```

If this raises an error, you need to set your `PYTHONPATH` environment variable in a way that it contains the path to your django directory.